# Firefox in ubuntu cli GLib-CRITICAL error

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, selenium, testing, jenkins

I have installed Firefox on my ubuntu server so I can run selenium testing through jenkins linked to bitbucket.

Jenkins told me that it didnt have access to firefox so I installed it with

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

this installed firefox version 38. the tests continued to give errors like this

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host    
127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

(process:28482): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 
'sys_page_size == 0' failed

Error: no display specified

(process:28489): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 
'sys_page_size == 0' failed

Error: no display specified
```

when I check the version this error comes up to. I have fully removed firefox and installed from the tar file to version 35 since I read that this could fix the problem.

It didn't fix it, the error comes back the exact same but the version has been changed to 35.

This is the Main of script that Jenkins is running

```
public class Test {
protected WebDriver driver;

@Before  
public void setUp(){        
driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

} //End Before

@Test

public void testGoogleSearch() { 

   // Find the text input element by its name          
WebElement element =  driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
   // Enter something to search for          
element.sendKeys("Selenium testing tools cookbook");
   // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find             
//the form for us from the element            
element.submit();

System.out.println("You have just logged into the  google6 website");

} //End of google search

@After   
public void tearDown() throws Exception {       
//Close the browser

driver.quit();
}
}//end
```

I don't believe the script is the problem but I thought that I would try to build a full picture.

Any help fixing this firefox error is really appreciated. Thanks

**Update 1**

I am using Maven and the version of selenium is 2.45.0

**Update 2**

I am running firefox headlessly

Comment: Can u kindly tell us which selenium version you are using.Are u running your test through maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is, you are not running a X-Server, so the Firefox can't connect to a display. This is why you get the

> Error: no display specified

which should be your main issue...

To solve this you need to set up Xvfb or a "real" X-Server, depending on what kind of server you have and address the exposed display of it correctly (i.e. run your selenium server process with DISPLAY=:1 if your xvfb happens to be running on display :1).

[This site](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless) helped me to get a hold of this issue some time back. Alternatively check out the [docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) project from Selenium itself. If you have the means to spin up a docker container on your machine that should be the quickest way to get around that issue (If not, going through their files provides a good understanding of how one can setup a headless Selenium environment on a ubuntu machine)

Wish you good luck with your issue and welcome to this cozy part of hell called headless testing ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tried your script using **Firefox 39** in ubuntu with **selenium 2.46.0** it was working fine

I think your version of Selenium is probably not compatible with your version of Firefox. Try using selenium 2.46.0

You can get the Maven dependency for selenium 2.46.0 [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp)

Hope this helps you...

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response, but I don't understand why I would see the "GLib-CRITICAL" error when I just check "firefox --version" if it had anything to do with selenium. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Hi @argo I think it looks like a problem with GStreamer.Try to set the media.gstreamer.enabled pref to false on the about:config page

Comment: sorry if this question seems stupid but I'm not quite sure where this "about:config page" is, do I need to go into where I have firefox installed on the server? because I am purely running firefox through the cmd line on my server when it is called by the test scripts.

Comment: @arg0 you have open the firefox and go to about config page and set media.gstreamer.enabled to false.Kindly refer the above screenshot

Comment: I dont think I can get the window open because im trying to run firefox on the server. I cant get it to display a window.

Comment: yeah that's the Idea of this I think, it will be run headless from the server. Do you think that's possible for debugging?

Comment: Yes debugging is still possible u can use log4j.Coming to your problem about firefox i think you need to install  X Virtual Framebuffer .Kindly refer the below article http://superuser.com/questions/855835/checking-firefox-version-using-cmd-and-gives-error